# uiview and uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, nsnotifications, uianimation

i am creating a dropdown button in my app. Like a pop-up control which is available in webapps. so when i click on a button, a new `UIView` containing a `UIPickerView` appears. i user beginanimations and commitanimations for dispalying and hiding the `UIView`. the new uiview is half the size of the scrollview.

I want that whenever the new uiview appears, the size of the scrollview should alter so that the i can scroll through the entire view. something like, when a keyboard appears, we reassign the size of scrollview, so that we can scroll entire view.

So how will i know, when the uiview appears. Is there a notification for beginanimations and commitanimations like for keyboard (UIKeyboardDidHideNotification)

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if the subview you create and show have a viewController, `-(void)viewWillAppear` method of the viewController will be called on every appearance of that view.

In that method, you can somehow get the superview (for example calling `nextResponder` method) and resize the superview according to your needs.

Hope that helps.